# Create single Bitmap from multiple sources produce corrupted image

Tags: java, android, http

I've been trying to simulate reading an image from a source online using http Range header from 2 different HttpURLConnection, However, the resulting image is always corrupted. If you look at the code below, if i only used the bytes from the first connection to create the Bitmap, I get half the image rendered correctly, but when I try to create new array of bytes which contains both arrays to create Bitmap, I get a corrupted image where small portions of the image are visible

WHy is that?

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
int imageSize = connection.getContentLength();
connection.disconnect();

int threadSize = (int)imageSize/2;                  


byte[] thread1 = new byte[threadSize];
HttpURLConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
connection1.setDoInput(true);
connection1.setDoOutput(true);
String s1 = "bytes=0-"+(threadSize-1);
connection1.setRequestProperty("Range", s1);
connection1.connect();
String contentType1 = connection1.getContentType();
String contentRange1 = connection1.getHeaderField("content-range");
String acceptRange1 = connection1.getHeaderField("Accept-ranges");
int statusCode = connection1.getResponseCode();
int imageSize1 = connection1.getContentLength();
InputStream input1 = connection1.getInputStream();
input1.read(thread1);
input1.close();
connection1.disconnect(); 


downloadIndex += threadSize;

byte[] thread2 = new byte[lastThreadSize];
HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
connection2.setDoInput(true);
connection2.setDoOutput(true);
String s2 = "bytes="+threadSize+"-";
connection2.setRequestProperty("Range", s2);
connection2.connect();
String contentType2 = connection2.getContentType();
String contentRange2 = connection2.getHeaderField("content-range");
String acceptRange2 = connection1.getHeaderField("Accept-ranges");
int imageSize2 = connection2.getContentLength();
int statusCode2 = connection2.getResponseCode();
InputStream input2 = connection2.getInputStream();
input2.read(thread2);
input2.close();
connection2.disconnect(); 

int aLen = thread1.length;
int bLen = thread1.length;
byte[] c= new byte[aLen+bLen];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(x);
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);//, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Image stream formats like JPEG and PNG are not set up to create one giant image just by appending multiple streams.

I would do it like this:

- Download image data and create bitmap source 1.
- Download another image data create bitmap source 2.
- Create an empty bitmap dest.  Set the width and the height to show both your source bitmaps together.

  ```
  Bitmap dest = new Bitmap(width, height, config);
  ```
- Construct a `Canvas` using the dest `Bitmap`:

  ```
  Canvas c = new Canvas(dest);
  ```
- Draw each source bitmap into the `Canvas`:

  ```
   c.drawBitmap(src1, left1, top1, paint);
   c.drawBitmap(src2, left2, top2, paint);
  ```

Then bitmap `dest` will have both source images.